# Input of boost converter or charge pump in the energy harvest

Tags: voltage, boost, input, energy-harvesting, charge-pump

I read some paper about the energy harvest, and lots of paper said the induced voltage from, for example, the thermo-electric harvesting could be as low as tens of millivolts in a realistic case, so their input of boost or charge pump is less than 100 mV.

But in some paper, I found the author will set the input from 30 mV to 300 mV, some paper even set the input to 3V. Why? If the induced voltage is only tens of millivolts, then 100 mV should be unless, because you cannot have this high voltage, higher than 100 mV, to feed the boost or charge pump, then why do  some authors still let the voltage be so high? Maybe induced voltage can be higher than 100 mV in some other kind of harvest. If so,can anyone give me an example?

Paper example 1(input 30mV~300mV):http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6419064/

Paper example 2 (input 450mV~3V):http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8234200/

Comment: It would be better if you could post a couple of example circuits from those papers. Then we could analyse them and explain.

Comment: If you don't subscribe to IEEE then who can read it? Is it a free subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage range for energy harvesting output is as diverse as there are different forms of energy harvesting. Each harvesting type will have it's own energy storage method, boot method and boost method.

You could be talking about RF energy harvesting, thermal difference harvesting, kinetic energy harvesting or solar harvesting.  To each it's own electronics. Study each in detail and you'll understand better.

Comment: According to what you know,in which energy harvest,the induced voltage will up to 300mV or 3V ?

Comment: I don't know. I only have a gut feeling which I'm not going to share as I'm not sure  about it. Why don't you read the papers you've linked to? I'm sure its in there what harvesting source they are using.